# How to extract frames from a YUV file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, format, yuv, mplayer

I have a YUV file and I want to obtain each frame in the form of a BMP file, how to go by doing this ? I have FFMPEG and MPlayer at my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -s widthxheight -i input.yuv image%05d.bmp
```

Please make sure to define the widht and height in pixels. For example for Full HD it would be `-s 1920x1080`, this is needed because the yuv format doesn't store any metadata for the video itself and you need to specify the resolution of the yuv file.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest u to first convert the .yuv file to .mp4 format by using this code.

`ffmpeg -s 640x480 -i input.yuv -ss 00:00:00 -c:v libx264 -s:v 640x480 -preset slow -t 00:00:20 output.mp4`

now extract the images from output.mp4 to .bmp format by using this code

`ffmpeg -i output.mp4 images%03d.bmp`

this will work.

a little explanantion of the above codes so that u can change the code according to ur needs.

-s 640x480 sets the resolution of the mp4 (u can change it to ur requirements)
-c:v libx264 sets the encoder to  do encoding in libx264
-preset slow (this again change it to ur requirements ultrafast, medium etc)
-t sets the output file time. here i have set it 20 seconds.(remember format is hh:mm:ss.ms where ms is milliseconds)

image%03d.bmp is given as output. so this means the output files will be saved as image001.bmp,image002.bmp ...

or just image%d.bmp outputs as image1.bmo,image2.bmp and so on

hope this helps

Comment: Isn't it possible to use ffmpeg to convert the yuv to bmp at the first stage? I mean does `ffmpeg -i input.yuv images%03d.bmp` not work?